# IOKit and getting unique ID's

Tags: c++, macos, iokit

I am using: IOServiceGetMatchingServices

```
kr = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault,
IOServiceNameMatching("AppleUSBEHCI"), &io_objects);
```

I am looking for how I find out information about the internal HD as the above will prob USB device.

I cannot seem to find a list or anything that would tell me this.

Essentially I am looking for a way to get a unique ID from the system. On Windows the other developer uses the hard disk id.

Can anyone shed some light on these values?

Comment: I believe this is not a good way to identify a Mac uniquely. Macs have a serial-number that should be available programmatically (as you can see it in both the "About this Mac" and in "System-Report", and will not change even if the hard-drive is replaced. There are also lower-level unique identifiers at the T2 security chip - but I don't have a clue as to how to get to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the command line, you can use the `ioreg` tool to explore the IO Kit registry. For Lion or Older, you can also use the convenient IORegistryExplorer GUI tool from Apple's Hardware IO Tools package. (it crashes on Mountain Lion)

For looking at internal hard drive properties, this is a pretty good start:

```
ioreg -irc IOAHCIBlockStorageDevice -w 0
```

Which on my MacBook Air yields:

```
+-o IOAHCIBlockStorageDevice  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOBlockStorageDevice:IOAHCIBlockStorageDevice, id 0x100000216, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (472 ms), retain 7>
  | {
  |   "IOCFPlugInTypes" = {"24514B7A-2804-11D6-8A02-003065704866"="SMARTLib.plugin"}
  |   "device-type" = "Generic"
  |   "IOStorageFeatures" = {"Unmap"=Yes}
  |   "Device Characteristics" = {"Logical Block Size"=512,"Product Name"="APPLE SSD TS256C                        ","Medium Type"="Solid State","Physical Block Size"=512,"SATA Features"=23,"Serial Number"="        X06S10H7THRZ","Product Revision Level"="CJAA0201"}
  |   "Protocol Characteristics" = {"Physical Interconnect"="SATA","Physical Interconnect Location"="Internal"}
  |   "SMART Capable" = Yes
  |   "IOMinimumSegmentAlignmentByteCount" = 4
  | }
  | 
  +-o IOBlockStorageDriver  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOStorage:IOBlockStorageDriver, id 0x100000219, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (471 ms), retain 8>
    +-o APPLE SSD TS256C Media  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOStorage:IOMedia, id 0x10000021a, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (471 ms), retain 11>
      +-o IOMediaBSDClient  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOMediaBSDClient, id 0x10000021b, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 6>
      +-o IOGUIDPartitionScheme  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOStorage:IOPartitionScheme:IOGUIDPartitionScheme, id 0x10000021d, !registered, !matched, active, busy 0 (3 ms), retain 8>
        +-o EFI system partition@1  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOStorage:IOMedia, id 0x100000263, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 9>
        | +-o IOMediaBSDClient  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOMediaBSDClient, id 0x100000266, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 6>
        +-o Customer@2  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOStorage:IOMedia, id 0x100000264, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (2 ms), retain 11>
        | +-o IOMediaBSDClient  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOMediaBSDClient, id 0x100000267, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 7>
        +-o Recovery HD@3  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOStorage:IOMedia, id 0x100000265, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (3 ms), retain 9>
          +-o IOMediaBSDClient  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOMediaBSDClient, id 0x100000268, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 6>
```

You can get at these properties programmatically via the IOKit user library as you've already discovered for USB.

At a somewhat higher level, some of the information is also available via the Disk Arbitration Framework, via the [`DADiskCopyDescription` function](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DiskArbitration/Reference/DADisk_header_reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011609-CHDADiskhFunctions-DontLinkElementID_4). The device properties exposed via this function don't seem to be documented outside the `DADisk.h` header file, but they're fairly self-explanatory, e.g.:

```
extern const CFStringRef kDADiskDescriptionDeviceGUIDKey;      /* ( CFData       ) */
extern const CFStringRef kDADiskDescriptionDeviceInternalKey;  /* ( CFBoolean    ) */
extern const CFStringRef kDADiskDescriptionDeviceModelKey;     /* ( CFString     ) */
extern const CFStringRef kDADiskDescriptionDevicePathKey;      /* ( CFString     ) */
extern const CFStringRef kDADiskDescriptionDeviceProtocolKey;  /* ( CFString     ) */
extern const CFStringRef kDADiskDescriptionDeviceRevisionKey;  /* ( CFString     ) */
extern const CFStringRef kDADiskDescriptionDeviceUnitKey;      /* ( CFNumber     ) */
extern const CFStringRef kDADiskDescriptionDeviceVendorKey;    /* ( CFString     ) */
```

Comment: Can you help me understand how to obtain these pieces from A DSDiskRef? I am looking at `DADisk.c` and it looks like: `_diskRef  = DADiskCreateFromBSDName( kCFAllocatorDefault, daSession, [diskBSDName UTF8String] );
  diskDesc  = DADiskCopyDescription( _diskRef );` gets me a `DADiskRef` that contains a lot or pieces. How does one out put the `DADiskRef` pieces as Strings?

Comment: `DADiskCopyDescription()` returns a regular `CFDictionary` - the documentation for these is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFDictionaryRef/Reference/reference.html) but to e.g. get the vendor, you'd go `NSString* vendor = (NSString*)CFDictionaryGetValue(diskDesc, kDADiskDescriptionDeviceVendorKey);` - you can treat CFStrings as NSStrings, this is called toll-free-bridging. You'll need to retain that string if you want to keep it. Don't forget to release the dictionary with `CFRelease(diskDesc);` when you're done with it.

Comment: Beware that unlike Objective-C methods, CF functions don't take kindly to NULL objects, so check that the result of `DADiskCopyDescription()` isn't NULL before using it.

Comment: this is really helpful advice.

Comment: Your response helped me a tremendous amount and what I need to do seems very likely now. Explanation clear, concise and concise and no fluff. Thank you for that.

Comment: Actually, these constants are VERY FAR from "self-explanatory" and there is not a single damn documentation guide to tell you what each stands for, and when they are available, and what is "software" and what is "hardware" and what can be relied on across disconnections/reconnections and so on. I'm tearing my hair off trying to understand these constants.

Comment: @MottiShneor Have you tried printing the dictionary returned by `DADiskCopyDescription` for the volumes in your system? Seeing those example values should make a lot of those keys very clear. Depending on what you're trying to do, we may be way out in the weeds, so perhaps post a new question with what you're actually after.

Comment: @MottiShneor If you use the `[diskarbitration]` tag on the new question I'll definitely see it as that's one of the tags I watch.

Comment: of course I did, and thanks... I will eventually formalise a question here, and no doubt, [diskarbitration] will be one of its tags. I'm still struggling with direct IOKit calls though, to see if I can get what I need that way. It looks like DiskArbitration framework is just a "convenience wrapper" around IOKit programming that is... well... not for the faint of heart.

Comment: @MottiShneor The DA framework is definitely more than an IOKit wrapper. IOKit only deals with the block layer, DA also has a view of VFS layer (file systems) and communicates with the disk arbitration daemon. So there are plenty of tasks for which IOKit alone is insufficient. I have no idea what you‘re trying to do, so I can‘t say what‘s right for your task. (Again, we‘ve now strayed very far from the original question, you are probably best off asking a new question)

Comment: I  now posted my question tagged as you recommended... have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want to do is to look at the device descriptor and see if it has a serial number.  It is up to the device to supply a serial number, and it's possible that the number may not be unique if it is provided at all.  If the device has a custom descriptor, there may be useful in there too.

See the following on descriptors:
http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml

There appears to be a property to get the serial number on the HID Device wrapper class:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IOKit/Reference/IOHIDBase_header_reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012400

If that doesn't work, there should be a way to get direct access to the USB device and request the data you need.

Comment: can you elaborate just a little more in your answer? at what level are these "device descriptors"? are they IOKit? lower than that? stored as some binary blobs we should get somewhere? or maybe higher level APIs that I'm not aware of? and what "HID" stands for? I believe 2-3 introductory lines in your answer could be VERY helpful

Comment: Everything I am referencing pertains to the USB protocol and isn't specific to IOKit.  Check the links above for more info about descriptors.  Read this page for a background on USB and HID devices: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I'm interested in all "external, removable hard-drives" including both USB, camera-cards and even rotational old FireWire drives... Do I need to write specific code for each "family" of device connection types for obtaining such basic information such as "Serial number" ???